# How to add a popup window for a gridview item template control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, popup

I added a grid view and the data is bounded to gridview. I placed a linkbutton in a item templateNow when I click this link button a popup should appear. I tried using modalPopupExtender but it shows an error : `The TargetControlID of 'ModalPopupExtender1' is not valid. A control with ID 'lnkDownload' could not be found` as linkbutoon is in item template it could not be found.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="minidata2" CssClass="table"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="abstract">

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="projectid" HeaderText="MyFileId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="video" HeaderText="MyFileurl" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="abstract">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" PopupControlID="panel1" TargetControlID="lnkDownload" runat="server"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Now how to show a popup window while we clcik on link button

**Updated** Please check the below code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1">
          <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:GridView ID="minidata" CssClass="table"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="abstract">

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="pid" HeaderText="MyFileId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="video" HeaderText="MyFileurl" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="abstract">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" PopupControlID="panel1" TargetControlID="Button1"  runat="server"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

      <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel1" style="display:none;">
          <div>
          <asp:Label runat="server" Text="sacca"></asp:Label>
          <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:LinkButton runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
              </div>

      </asp:Panel>
              </ContentTemplate>
          <Triggers>
              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="minidata" />
          </Triggers>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ModalPopupExtender1` is not able to find `lnkDownload` which is inside gridview
hence try something like this

```
<asp:GridView ID="minidata2" CssClass="table"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="abstract">

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="projectid" HeaderText="MyFileId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="video" HeaderText="MyFileurl" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="abstract">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClientClick='openmodelpopup();' ></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none;" />
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" PopupControlID="panel1" TargetControlID="Button1" runat="server"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>


 <script type="text/javascript">
     function openmodelpopup() {

            document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID %>').click();
        }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a button or linkbutton outside gridview targeting Modalpop.

```
<asp:GridView ID="minidata2" CssClass="table"  runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="abstract">

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="projectid" HeaderText="MyFileId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="video" HeaderText="MyFileurl" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="abstract">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
      <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
      <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" PopupControlID="panel1" TargetControlID="lnkbtn" runat="server"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Then On linkbutton click event fire from gridview show your modal popup:

```
protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your code           
        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

Comment: But in my item template I binded abstract as datakeyname (i.e a file will be downloaded while user clicks link button ). Here a popup should display.

Comment: ok , no issue  put your file download code above `modalpopextender.Show()` . your file will be downloaded and pop will appear.

Comment: this linkbutton click event is for itemtemplate linkbutton not for outside link button.

Comment: But I need a popup for link button in a gridview. Is it possible

Comment: yes this is popup for link button in a gridview. may this link will help http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Use-AJAX-Modal-Popup-Extender-inside-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: I updated my question. When I try to run the above code it does't work.

Comment: When I click on link button in grid view it executes normally with out any popup. When I click on target control (i.e Button1) and then on link button in grid view nothing happens..( The event doesn't raised)

Comment: Instead of Scriptmanager try ToolScriptManager, may help you : `<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="tool1" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98774/discussion-between-rojalin-sahoo-and-crazyy-net).